# Android tab with view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabview

I want to have a tab view, each tab contains a view pager which in turn contains a listview. Intrinsically, the swipe left or right should be handled by the view pager inside a tab rather than swithching a tab to its sibling tab. How should I approach this use case most neatly? BTW, I am not using ActionBar.
thank you

Comment: There are so many examples, google it first.

Comment: Tab's inside activity / fragment ?

Comment: inside an activity, i am not using fragment. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in my current project, except i have made tabs and each tab has a ListView.

First you will have to make an Activity which will have ViewPager and SlidingTabLayout.[This will help yo do that.](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Second you will need to create fragments which will again have ViewPager and another fragment which will have ListView inside it.(fragment inside a fragment)
[Have a look here also](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)